# Installing Scipy.stats on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, scipy, pythonanywhere

At pythonanywhere I want to upload the page that works fine on my computer. While installing the scipy.stats module using:

```
pip install -U scipy.stats
```

in my virtual environment, I get this response:

```
Collecting scipy.stats

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement scipy.stats (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for scipy.stats
```

checking with pip list, I see that scipy (0.19.0) is installed.

When I replace the import statement in my actual code with

```
from scipy import stats
```

and migrate, I get an error where the last few lines are these:

```
from scipy import stats
  File "/home/Equinox/.virtualenvs/homepage/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 105, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion as _NumpyVersion
ImportError: No module named 'scipy._lib'
```

I do have numpy also installed. And it would not find a module 'scipy._lib' (and no 'scipy._lib._version' either) if I try to install it. How would I proceed now? How can I install scipy.stats?

Thanks

Comment: did you solve your issue? I'm having the same problem now

Answer (score 2):

scipy.stats is already installed if scipy is available (it is part of scipy).

You then just need to import it correctly!

Try:

```
from scipy import stats
```

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong and should read how import is working in python. And *i get an error* is not a useful description!

Comment: I published my previous comment incompletely.